# How to reliably cancel a Kotlin coroutine or thread (especially when readln() is involved)

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As a training exercise, I'm trying to write a Boggle simulator in Kotlin. It's a console application that runs on the JVM on Linux. This is proving to be much easier than it was in C, except for one small detail - the interruptible timer.

In the travel version of the Boggle game (which I own and play regularly), one starts the game timer by pressing a button. If the game has to be interrupted prematurely for some reason, this can be done by pressing the button again. In C, I had the needed features to check for any keyboard input, and only continue waiting for the timer (or a keypress) if there wasn't keyboard input. I'm not sure how to do that in Kotlin, or if it even can be done when running it in the JVM. So, I took the second-most-obvious approach - multithreading.

First, I tried to use kotlinx.coroutines, doing something like this:

```
runBlocking {
    var done = false
    val waitForEnter = launch {
        readln()
        done = true
    }
    val waitForTimer = launch {
        delay(5000L)
        playTone()
        done = true
    }

    while (true) {
        if (done) {
            waitForEnter.cancel()
            waitForTimer.cancel()
        }

        delay(1000L)
    }
}
```

The idea was that, if either task should finish before the other, both would terminate at the same time. What happened instead was that the timer never went off at all, until the user pressed Enter.

Out of curiosity, I removed the delay in the waitForTimer coroutine, but left it beyond the waitForEnter coroutine. Sure enough, no sound played until I pressed Enter. My understanding was that, when using asynchronous programming, a blocking call like `readLn()` wouldn't jam things up. Obviously I was mistaken.

After a bit more fiddling, I got frustrated and switched to using threads instead:

```
var done = false
val waitForEnter = thread {
    readln()
    done = true
}
val waitForTimer = thread {
    Thread.sleep(5000L)
    playTone()
    done = true
}

while (true) {
    if (done) {
        waitForEnter.interrupt()
        waitForTimer.interrupt()
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000L)
}
```

But guess what! Thread.interrupt() does *not* interrupt a `readln()` call! And I saw enough dire warnings about not using anything akin to `Thread.stop()` (which doesn't even exist anymore I don't think?) to not want to tread in that zone.

I'm probably missing something, since I just started learning Kotlin yesterday. I now know two ways that don't work. What's one that will?

Comment: I'm not an expert in OS internals, but I believe it is technically impossible to stop a blocking call, no matter the language. This is a limitation of OSes. What did you do exactly in C? Did you use functions like `pthread_create`/`pthread_kill`? I believe they are not safe and they don't guarantee the call is interrupted. The proper solution is to not start a blocking call in the first place if you need to finish early. We should use non-blocking mode. In the case of Java/Kotlin, that may be tricky as I don't know if we can switch stdin into a non-blocking mode. We probably can do this in C.

Comment: @broot In C, I avoided blocking and multithreading at all. I could use a kbhit() function to detect if there was anything to read from stdin, and then if there was I could immediately do getche() to read it (which would for sure not block since it only read one character and kbhit() told me there was a character to read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple topics to cover here.

First, no, using coroutines doesn't mean that blocking calls somehow become non-blocking, so we can safely use blocking I/O in our code. Actually, it is kind of opposite. While using asynchronous frameworks it is disallowed to make any blocking operations as they affect the responsiveness of the whole application. In your code sample based on coroutines, you actually blocked the whole application by doing `readln()`, so it couldn't even start running a timer.

Second, it is not possible to forcefully cancel/interrupt/kill/stop a coroutine, a thread or a blocking I/O operation. Well, there are ways to kill them e.g. `Thread.stop()` you mentioned, but they are not safe to do, they may cause mess or even not at all work. Both thread interrupting and coroutines cancelling is cooperative and that means the thread/coroutine has to actively check its state. While running a blocking I/O, interrupts/cancellations are ignored. I believe this is actually a limitation of operating systems and it behaves in a similar way no matter the language.

Common solutions to this problem are:

- Use non-blocking I/O.
- Use I/O timeouts.
- Close the stream/file handle/etc. from another thread.

Unfortunately, I believe none of these will work with stdin in Java.

Another solution is to use asynchronous I/O pattern. We can spawn a thread which blocks on reading from the stdin, then it puts the data into some kind of a buffer, so it can be read from there without blocking. In this solution we should never read from the stdin directly, but only from our asynchronous wrapper. The simplest implementation based on Java threads would be by using a `BlockingQueue`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val queue = SynchronousQueue<String>()
    thread(isDaemon = true) {
        while (true) {
            queue.put(readln())
        }
    }

    println("Read #1: ${queue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)}")
    println("Read #2: ${queue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)}")
}
```

It may be counter-intuitive to use a `BlockingQueue` as it is clearly blocking, but it doesn't block on I/O, only on the thread synchronization. Compared to reading from the `InputStream` directly, we get additional features like: read timeouts, support for interruptions, we can check if reading is possible without blocking, etc.

In practice, we should probably wrap it into a class, add some extra functionality, maybe provide a buffer, etc. If using Kotlin coroutines, we can do pretty much the same by using a `Channel`.

Comment: If anyone notice a misinformation anywhere in the answer, please let me know. I might be not entirely correct in some places.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since `readln()` is blocking call, it will block the Thread that `launch` coroutine is running on, which in your case is Thread of `runBlocking`: `main`. Other codes will not run while `main` is blocked. Lets dispatch `readln()` to separate Thread or Thread-pool. We can use `newSingleThreadContext("InputThread")` or `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()`

```kotlin
    fun main() = runBlocking {
        println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Start")
        var done = false
        val inputThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
        val waitForEnter = launch(inputThread) {
            println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Waiting for input:")
            readln()
            println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Input Done")
            done = true
        }
        val waitForTimer = launch {
            println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Timer start")
            delay(5000L)
            println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Timer Done")
            done = true
        }
    
        while (true) {
            if (done) {
                println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Cancel Both")
                waitForEnter.cancel()
                waitForTimer.cancel()
                inputThread.close()
                break
            }
    
            delay(1000L)
        }
    }
```

If you wait 5 sec, output is:

```
[main @coroutine#1] Start
[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2] Waiting for input:
[main @coroutine#3] Timer start
[main @coroutine#3] Timer Done
[main @coroutine#1] Cancel Both
```

If you hit Enter, output is:

```
[main @coroutine#1] Start
[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2] Waiting for input:
[main @coroutine#3] Timer start

[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2] Input Done
[main @coroutine#1] Cancel Both
```

2. In above first output, program didn't exit, `readline()` is still alive even its Thread and Coroutine is cancelled. If you check its source code, it calls `LineReader.readLine(System.in, Charset.defaultCharset())`, `System.in` is the `InputStream` it is reading from. So i tried closing it which worked. I had to copy/paste implementation of `LineReader` which is internal class under `kotlin.io.Console.kt`:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Start")
    var done = false
    val inputThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
    val inputStream = System.`in`
    val waitForEnter = launch(inputThread) {
        println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Waiting for input:")
        LineReader.readLine(inputStream, Charset.defaultCharset())
        println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Input Done")
        done = true
    }
    val waitForTimer = launch {
        println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Timer start")
        delay(5000L)
        println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Timer Done")
        done = true
    }

    while (true) {
        if (done) {
            println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Cancel Both")
            waitForEnter.cancel()
            waitForTimer.cancel()
            inputStream.close() // Throws IOException, try/catch it
            inputThread.close()
            break
        }

        delay(1000L)
    }
}

private object LineReader {
   // copy paste
}
```

If you wait 5 sec, output is:

```
[main @coroutine#1] Start
[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2] Waiting for input:
[main @coroutine#3] Timer start
[main @coroutine#3] Timer Done
[main @coroutine#1] Cancel Both
[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2] Input Done
```

If you hit Enter, output is:

```
[main @coroutine#1] Start
[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2] Waiting for input:
[main @coroutine#3] Timer start

[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2] Input Done
[main @coroutine#1] Cancel Both
```

*Use `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` in `Run -> Edit Configurations -> VM Options` to see coroutine name printed as above*

Comment: The problem here is that we can only try to read a character once per the app execution, because we closed the stdin permanently.

Comment: @broot probably... I wonder how "so suggested C solution" works

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov The C solution I was using is here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285893/dos-based-boggle-simulator The trick to it is the use of kbhit(), which never blocks and can tell me whether trying to read from stdin will block or not.